# Execute StoredProcedure more than once

Tags: java, spring, oracle, function

I have the following code which creates a subclass of `StoredProcedure`and executes it. What I want to achieve is to use the same object with new SQL and new parameters more than once. Unfortunately when I set new SQL and declare new parameters I get an exception.

Is it somehow possible to "generify" class to execute more than one SQL with new parameters ? **In my particular example more than one question**

**The code**

```
package procedures;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyProcedure extends StoredProcedure {

    private static String SQL = "hr.get_size";

    public MyProcedure(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, SQL);
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("param_out", Types.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("param_in", Types.VARCHAR));
        setFunction(true);
        compile();
    }

    public Object execute(String tableName) {
        Map in = new HashMap();
        in.put("param_in", tableName);
        Map out = execute(in);
        if (!out.isEmpty()) {
            return out.get("param_out");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**The call which raises exception:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
    MyProcedure myProcedure = applicationContext.getBean(MyProcedure.class);
    System.out.println(myProcedure.execute("employees"));

    myProcedure.setSql("hr.get_all_tables");
    myProcedure.declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("param_out", Types.VARCHAR));
    myProcedure.setFunction(true);
    myProcedure.compile();
    System.out.println(myProcedure.execute());
}
```

**The exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cannot add parameters once the query is compiled
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.RdbmsOperation.declareParameter(RdbmsOperation.java:278)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.declareParameter(StoredProcedure.java:99)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MyProcedure` class should not extended `StoredProcedure`, but instead delegate to it.

I think what you are doing is an example of the misuse of class extension. You should only extend a class or interface if your subclass is going to respect the behaviour of the super-class (see [Liskov Substitution Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). The `StoredProcedure` class encapsulates a single procedure and is read-only, which provides certain guarantees to classes using it. Your class can have the procedure and parameters change in the background, so it is a different thing.

You should instead make `StoredProcedure` a private member of your class and delegate calls to it (see [Delegation Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)).

When you need to access a new stored procedure you just throw away the old `StoredProcedure` object and `new` another one. You can just create an anonymous inner class if you want:

```
    StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure(ds, SQL) {
        public Object execute(String tableName) {
            Map in = new HashMap();
            in.put("param_in", tableName);
            Map out = execute(in);
            if (!out.isEmpty()) {
                return out.get("param_out");
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
```

If something in your code needs to access the actual stored procedure object you can provide a getter to expose it.

Also see this article: [Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: `StoredProcedure` class is abstract class - I can't create an instance of it.

Comment: I added an example of creating an anonymous class. But in the end, you are going to have to create a new `StoredProcedure` object for each procedure. I would not waste time trying to find ways avoiding doing that.